# Evaluating $\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{2^n (n!)^2}$

Tags: real-analysis, limits, indeterminate-forms

> Can you please explain how should I evaluate this limit
> $$\lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{(2n)!}{2^n (n!)^2}$$

I know the solution is $\geq1$ but I don't know how I can just simplify like this but I stuck here $$\frac{2n(2n-1)(2n-2)...1}{2^n(n(n-1)(n-2)...1)}$$ I don't know if I should simplify it like that as I said the answer is $\geq1$ but  my textbook doesn't explain why?

Comment: Stirling's formula?

Comment: Note that, if your transcribed it correctly, you have

$$\frac{(2n)!}{2^n(n!)^2}=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n n!} \frac{1}{n!} = \prod_{i=1}^n \frac{2i-1}{i}$$

hence your sequence goes to infinity.

Comment: In this case, Stirling's formula is not strictly needed!

Comment: @Dunnò000 yes I double check that and it's correct but the answer is $\geq1$ is it stirling formula I don't understand it can you guys explain it i'm studying calc 2 right now

Comment: Well $\infty$ is $\ge 1$. Using Stirling you can deduce how fast it goes to infinity. It should go like $\frac{2^n}{\sqrt{\pi n}}$, meaning that if you multiply your sequence by $\frac{\sqrt{\pi n}}{2^n}$ you get something with limit $1$ for $n\to \infty$.

Comment: Integration by parts gives
$$a_n=\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{2}{\pi}\int_{0}^{\pi/2}\left(\sin\theta\right)^{2n}\,d\theta $$
hence $\lim_{n\to +\infty}\frac{(2n)!}{{\color{red}4^n}n!^2}$ is zero by the monotone/dominated convergence theorem. From this identity it is not difficult to get that the LHS behaves like $\frac{1}{\sqrt{\pi\left(n+\tfrac{1}{4}\right)}}$ as $n\to +\infty$.
From the extended binomial theorem we also have
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{4^n}\binom{2n}{n}x^n = \frac{1}{\sqrt{1-x}} $$
for any $x\in[-1,1)$, such that
$$ \sum_{n=0}^{N} a_n a_{N-n} = 1. $$

Answer (score 3):

Let $a_n=\frac{(2n)!}{2^n (n!)^2}$ and consider the limit of the ratio
$$\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}=\frac{(2n+2)!}{2^{n+1} ((n+1)!)^2}\cdot \frac{2^n (n!)^2}{(2n)!}=\frac{(2n+2)(2n+1)}{2 (n+1)^2}\to \ ?$$
Do you know any theorem about limit of sequences which involves such ratio?

Comment: it is ratio test and the answer of this ratio test is 2 but I  
do not understand what does this have to do with the limit at infinity can you explain it ?

Comment: Yes, it is $2$. Now you should know that if the limit of the ratio is greater than $1$ then the limit of the original sequence is $+\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Taking logarithm, the sequence term becomes

$$\sum_{k=1}^{2n}\ln(k)-2\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)-n\ln(2)$$

$$=\sum_{k=n+1}^{2n}\ln(k)-\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(k)-n\ln(2)$$

$$=\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(\frac{k+n}{k})-n\ln(2)$$

$$n\Bigl(\frac 1n\sum_{k=1}^n\ln(1+\frac nk)-\ln(2)\Bigr)$$

The Riemann sum goes to $$\int_0^1(\ln(x+1)-\ln(x))dx=2\ln(2)+1$$

The limit will be $+\infty$.